# Only one of these subviews is being shown

Tags: ios, uiimageview, uistoryboardsegue

I am passing 2 imageviews to the next view using a segue and only one of the images is being shown. I can't find a fix for this anywhere.

Code for the segue:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqual:@"CloudyBlue"]) {

        Level1_4inch_White *dest = [segue destinationViewController];
        CloudyBlue.frame = CGRectMake(78, 277, 139, 100);
        CloudyBlue1.frame = CGRectMake(363, 277, 139, 100);
        [dest.view addSubview:CloudyBlue];
        [dest.view addSubview:CloudyBlue1];

    }
}
```

UPDATE: As to one of the comments, here is what It looks like:
There is suppose to be another eye on the left.

[image]

EDIT:

```
 @interface WeatherEyeViewController_4inch_White : UIViewController {

    IBOutlet UIImageView *CloudyBlue;
    IBOutlet UIImageView *CloudyBlue1;

}
```

I figured it out! Instead of creating it like above. I create them like this and it works!

```
    UIImageView *CloudyBlue = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(78, 277, 139, 100)];
    UIImageView *CloudyBlue1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(363, 277, 139, 100)];
    [CloudyBlue setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cloudy-Eye-Blue.png"]];
    [CloudyBlue1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cloudy-Eye-Blue.png"]];
```

Comment: Unless this is an iPad (or an iPhone in landscape), the frame of `CloudBlue1` if off the right edge of the screen.

Comment: The width of an iPhone/iPod in portrait is 320px.

Comment: Shouldn't you add the subviews to the destination controller instead of self?

Comment: Yes this is a landscape app.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint here, is the second image view nil? Check to make sure the image object within the image view is not nil. Try adding a background color to the second image view, to see if the frame actually shows up.

Comment: I set the backgrounded color to black and the only one image being shown is the CloudyBlue, not the CloudyBlue1

Comment: Can you show the code how you create cloudyBlue and cloudyBlue1?

Comment: Is that a paste of your code as it doesn't all seem to match up. Are these outlets or not? Why do you set the frames twice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! Instead of creating it like above. I create them like this and it works!

```
UIImageView *CloudyBlue = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(78, 277, 139, 100)];
UIImageView *CloudyBlue1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(363, 277, 139, 100)];
[CloudyBlue setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cloudy-Eye-Blue.png"]];
[CloudyBlue1 setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Cloudy-Eye-Blue.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't hardcore the frames using `CGRectMake`. Instead you should be setting the frames in the storyboard, or, rather, setting the frames by specifying the auto-layout constraints. By using auto-layout your views will change is suitable ways when the interface is rotated.

Comment: The interface is always in landscape, never in portrait. Also i am not using Auto-Layout, I must have it check out for it to work

Comment: Have you checked both the views exist?

Comment: It is the same view (Levels 1 view), it just i think that one of the subviews is covering the other and not allowing it to be shown because only cloudyBlue i think is covering it